# Samba permissions

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, nas

I'm setting up a NAS server, and I'm trying to configure samba. I can see the share on my windows clinet, but i can't write anything in it.

My smb.conf looks like this:

```
[global]
workgroup=WORKGROUP
security=share

[myshare]
comment = Share
guest ok=yes
read only=no
path=/media/disk
browseable=yes
writeable=yes
```

I can see the directory, read all the files, but cannot write anything. In fact, if I look at smbstatus, I see RDONLY on the share, so something probably is missing.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you mounting the drive? An entry in `fstab` or through other means?

Answer (score 1):

You should change its permission :

if you want to give guest full permission :

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/disk -R ( -R for recursive)
```

You can change the permission as you want and it will be applied to samba share.

Comment: No this is not the problem. I did that, but still the same issue. Besides, my folder is mounted 755 with user and group root.

Comment: @nux Modding permissions in /media does not always work. Depends on how the volume is being mounted. `fstab` will mount them with whatever args are made in the entry. My external USB drive mounts with my user permissions, but an `fstab` entry for my NAS volume mounts with the special args (UID/GID) I made for it to be used by my DVR system.